# StyledTab component not accepting To or component properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use tabs as links but I can't find any where that explains how to do it when you are styling a tab component. I get the syntax that if you use a Tab component you should do this:

```
<Tab value="..." component={Link} to="/"  >
```

However if I have styled the Tab before and created an additional component like below, I can't find anything. I did this because I couldn't style the tab directly and I found this solution.

```
//Styled Tab

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(() => ({
  ...theme.typography.estimateBtn,
  borderRadius: "50px",
  marginLeft: "25px",
  marginRight: "25px",
  height: "50px",
}));

// nav container 

const ToolBarCom: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  // handles classes for non react elements
  const classes = useStyles();

  const onChangeHandler = (e: React.SyntheticEvent, value: number) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <ToolBar disableGutters>
      {/* <Typography variant='h3'>Arc Development</Typography> */}
      <img src={logo} alt='company logo' className={classes.logo} />
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        textColor='secondary'
        indicatorColor='primary'
        className={classes.tabsContainer}
        variant='scrollable'
        scrollButtons='auto'>
        <StyledTab value={0} label='Home' />
        <StyledTab value={1} label='Services' />
        <StyledTab value={2} label=' The Revolution' />
        <StyledTab value={3} label='About Us'  />
        <StyledTab value={4} label=' Contact Us' />
      </Tabs>
      <StyledButton variant='contained' color='secondary'>
        Free Trial
      </StyledButton>
    </ToolBar>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restyle the Tab with useStyle hook. You have to find the root of the tab component. I couldn't find any documentation for the issue above. See below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  logo: {
    height: "5em",
  },
  tabsContainer: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
    color: "white",
  },
  tab: {
    "&.MuiTab-root": {
      ...theme.typography.tab,
      minWidth: 10,
      marginLeft: "25px",
    },
  },
}));
```